# How configure Zimbra to bounce mails over a given size limit?

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, zimbra, attachment

How to configure Zimbra to bounce/notify email to sender due to over attach size from external mails like Gmail, Yahoo, etc..

I am using Zimbra open source edition. Undelivered mails are not bouncing to the sender for higher message size / attach size.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extended Wiki entry on the Zimbra Support Site that explains this in detail.

http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Configuring_maxmessagesize

Comment: Given solution not woking for me, MX record for our domain points to dyndns.com, where upto 50 MB messages are received. From dyndns setup is to push mails to a zimbra (postfix) server inside the corporate firewall, where in message limit is set to 5MB.

When incoming messages are more than 5MB, we are expecting some kind of notification - it can be bounce notification, email to admin or logging of such actions. Can you help, how to setup this? Or where in postfix logs can we look for error notifications?

Thanks alot for your time, and I hope i've asked the question correctly.